# Problems applying subscription to RHEL 7.8

Tags: linux, rhel7, subscription

I have an account on access.redhat.com and hence downloaded RHEL 7.8 under Developer Edition. But after installing it on laptop, when I try to register the product it throws the following error:

```
HTTP error (401) unauthorized
```

BTW, my account details are correctly entered. Has anyone got RHEL 7.8 registered under its Developer Subscription model which is free of cost.

Comment: Does the system name have a role here? I had left `localhost.localdomain` in the subscription manager text box meant for entering system name.

Comment: Yes, registering systems works. Exactly what did you try to do?

Comment: Downloaded ISO, trying to install using VirtualBox, connected the newly installed VMs running RHEL7.8 to internet but it keeps throwing unable to subscribe. My account details are valid and the system name and the subscription host of redhat to connect to is left as default.

Comment: Are you connected directly to the Internet? You don't have to go through a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, it end up being my dns server was not accepting requests so address was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
subscription-manager register --username "my username only and not email" --password "my password"
```